# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @Form NVARCHAR(36)
SET @Form = NEWID()

SELECT *
INTO #s
FROM [2290_Form]
WHERE PK_2290F_key = @inputkey

INSERT INTO [2290_Form]
VALUES (@Form, 
    (SELECT #s.FK_C_B_key FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.is_vin_correction FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.is_amendment FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.amendment_category FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.is_final_return FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.first_used_month FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.tax_year FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.tax_amt FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.additional_amt FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.credit_amt FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.payment_mode FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.consent_tag FROM #s),
    (SELECT #s.status FROM #s), GETDATE(), NULL)

INSERT INTO [2290_Vehicles]
VALUES (NEWID(), @Form, 
    (SELECT vin FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT category FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT is_logging FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT is_agricultural FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT is_mileage_exceed FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT weight_current FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT weight_old FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT credit_reason FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT buyer FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT effective_date FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey),
    (SELECT tax_amt FROM [2290_Vehicles] WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey), GETDATE(), NULL)

SET @Formkey = @Form
```

I am getting error is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: Your subquery returns too many rows. Hence the error message

Comment: All selects after insert can be error prone

Comment: When your query returns more than one row at that time this types of errors occurs while set it in to variable.

Comment: You have a number of open questions.  If the answers provided helped you please consider [accepting them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This rewards the community member who helped you, makes it easier for other people with the same issue to find the answer and increases the odds of you receiving help in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Form NVARCHAR(36)
SET @Form = NEWID()

INSERT INTO dbo.[2290_Form]
SELECT @Form, FK_C_B_key, is_vin_correction, ..., GETDATE(), NULL
FROM dbo.[2290_Form]
WHERE PK_2290F_key = @inputkey

INSERT INTO dbo.[2290_Vehicles]
SELECT NEWID(), @Form, vin, category, ..., tax_amt, GETDATE(), NULL
FROM dbo.[2290_Vehicles]
WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your subqueries to `2290_Vehicles` returns more than one row. To find which that might be, try this:

```
select FK_2290_F_key
from [2290_Vehicles]
group by FK_2290_F_key
having count(FK_2290_F_key) > 1
```